# Restoring Jenkins job history that got deleted during a rename

Tags: windows, jenkins

I renamed my jenkins job, and it took about 3 hours. While waiting for this horrifically long time, I watched the filesystem to see the original folder (96gig) slowly moving to the new folder (4gig), and then the old folder was gone and I was only left with 4gigs... lovely.

I was able to run Recuva and recover all the deleted builds from the filesystem, and I put them in the same spot where all the builds SHOULD go, but they are not showing up in the history.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Of course there is no backup, so this is the only place that the build history exists...

Comment: After restoring the builds did you restart Jenkins or (preferably) run _Restore Configuration from Disk_?

Comment: I have done both restart jenkins and restore configuration from disk. Right now, Jenkins is only showing 2 failed builds, builds 1 and 2 (which ran last night). My project used to be at build number... 3200 or so

Comment: It looks like the builds are created in a super messed up way. 

For example, with build 1:

There is a type of link folder called 1 that links to another folder in the same folder called "2016-08-31_20-43-24" which contains the actual files. 

If the build number 1 is literally only stored in this way, I might be completely screwed, because none of those links were able to be undeleted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated jenkins to the latest LTS and it shows the history now! Hooray!